# Global vs Local Vars when working with jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it better/faster to use a global variable when doing things within .each()? over many elements on a page?

```
$('.myClass').each(function (){
   myC = $(this)
   myH = myC.parent().height();
   myC.height(myH)
}
```

As opposed to:

```
$('.myClass').each(function (){
   var myC = $(this)
   var myH = myC.parent().height();
   myC.height(myH)
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use local variables unless you explicitly need global persistence and global access.  In this particular circumstances, you should be using local variables (the second option).

In case you're curious, local variables are slightly faster to access than global variables in most JS engines because the local scope is searched first before other scopes higher up, but this is not the reason to pick local vs. global.

Always use local variables unless you explictly NEED global variables.  And then when using global variables, you have to pick names carefully that will not conflict with anything else on your web page or in your project or in any libraries you might be using.  I name scope nearly all global variables into an object to avoid any conflict with other globals.

Also, NEVER use explicitly declared (I call them accidental) global variables either like in your first example.  If you want a global variable, declare it at the global scope.

If you need a variable to survive from one `.each()` function call to the next, you can define it one level up, but still a local variable like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('.myClass').each(function (){
       var myC = $(this);
       if (myC.height() > maxHeight) {
           maxHeight = myC.height();
       }
    }
    // maxHeight is set here
}
```

Comment: I thought it might be faster as in each ".each()" it just repalces that global var each time since once it's done, it doesn't need it anymore, so it becomes more a tray than 100s of new trays which each have one variable that never gets used again. Kinda thinking out aloud here. But thought I'd ask SO pros if it made sense.

Comment: The namespace pollution/potential conflict of globals is a much bigger downside.

Answer (score 2):

It's never better nor faster to use a global variable and you have no reason to do so, so no, don't do that!